# How can I write this using `field in` in rails way?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I learned that using `field in (a1,a2,a3)` is comparably faster than using = operator.

```
SELECT *
FROM user
WHERE Greeting IN ('hello', 'hi', 'hey')
```

How can I write above query in rails way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd do something like this:

```
users = User.where('greeting in (?)', %w{hello hi hey})
```

Rails will know what to do with an array, `%w{hello hi hey}`, as a value for a placeholder. Or, if you already had an array of strings:

```
h_words = [ 'hello', 'hi', 'hey' ]
users   = User.where('greeting in (?)', h_words)
# or even this
users   = User.where('greeting in (:words)', :words => h_words)
```

or, probably the most Railsy way, like this:

```
users = User.where(:greeting => %w{hello hi hey})
```

Comment: Does `User.where('greeting in (?)', h_words)` requires array elements in `h_words` to be sql injection safe? Does rails do that as if PHP does it in prepared statement?

Comment: @user482594: ActiveRecord will take care of properly escaping and encoding the placeholder values so you hand it an array of normal strings. You'd have to do it yourself if you used string interpolation though so don't do that unless absolutely necessary.